# Entity for joining multiple tables

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am using hibernate criteria query framework for generating reports. I have to provide sorting and filtering as well. Things were working fine when the data was confined to a single entity. However I have a requirement to join multiple entities and show the result in a single table. Following are the entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_profile")
@Where(clause = "deleted = 0")
public class UserProfile {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "middle_name")
    private String middleName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;        
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_data")
public class UserData {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "account_nonexpired")
    private Boolean accountNonExpired = true;

    @Column(name = "account_nonlocked")
    private Boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    @Column(name = "credentials_nonexpired")
    private Boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    private Boolean enabled = false;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role")
public class Role {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;
}
```

These entities have a common user name. Is it possible to create an entity which has no table but just contains these entities as fields? For eg:

```
public Class UserDataProfileRoleMapping{
    private UserProfile userProfile;
    private List<Role> role;
    private UserData userData;
}
```

I can create a mapping table but I was keeping it as a last resort.

**Edit**

The query which I want to fire is something like:

```
select * from user_data u, user_role r, user_profile up
where 
u.username = r.username and
r.username = up.username;
```

Comment: Do you just need the aggregated/joined information for displaying or do you really need a table with all that information? If it is the first case, you can create a DTO with the information you need and create a respective query.

Comment: I have to aggregate this information. However I also want to leverage Hibernate's criteria query api. Creating a DTO will entail handling sorting, filtering and pagination manually.

Comment: No, the DTO is just a plain POJO which will only hold the information/columns you need. I will create a quick example in an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You should create a POJO as a DTO which will hold exactly the information you need and use that instead of the actual entities. Let's assume we have three entities, `Order`, `OrderItem` and `Customer` and the query should be something like

```
SELECT Order.orderDate, Customer.name, OrderItem.amount
FROM Order
JOIN Customer ON Order.customerId = Customer.id
JOIN OrderItem ON Order.id = OrderItem.orderId
WHERE OrderItem.name = 'Puppet';
```

Now, the DTO would be:

```
public class ReturnDto {
    private Date date;
    private String customerName;
    private int amount;

    public ReturnDto(Date date, String customerName, int amount) {
        this.date = date;
        ...
    }

    // getters for the three properties
}
```

And in your DAO you could do something along the following lines:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ReturnDto> cQuery = cb.createQuery(ReturnDto.class);

Root<Order> orderRoot = cQuery.from(Order.class);
Join<Order, Customer> customerJoin = orderRoot.join(Order_.customer);
Join<Order, OrderItem> orderItemJoin = orderRoot.join(Order_.orderItems);

List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

criteria.add(cb.equal(orderItemJoin.get(OrderItem_.name), "Puppet");

// here you can do the sorting, e.g. - all with the criteria API!
cQuery.orderBy(...);
cQuery.distinct(true);

cQuery.select(cb.construct(ReturnDto.class,
    orderRoot.get(Order_.date),
    customerJoin.get(Customer_.name),
    orderItemJoin.get(OrderItem_.amount)
));

cQuery.where(cb.and(criteria.toArray(new Predicate[criteria.size()])));
List<ReturnDto> returnList = entityManager.createQuery(cQuery).getResultList();
```

Obviously, you cannot save the items in the returned list, but you get exactly the information you want and you can still handle things with the list, which you cannot handle with SQL/Criteria API.

*Update*: Just found this link, which may also help with the concept I used above: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/jpa-2-0-criteria-query-with-hibernate.html?utm_content=buffer0bd84&utm_source=buffer&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Buffer